# What is the lower bound of the given expression?

Tags: inequality

What is the lower bound of $\frac{a_1}{s-a_1}+\frac{a_2}{s-a_2}+...+\frac{a_n}{s-a_n}$ where $a_1,a_2,...a_n$ are positive numbers and $s=a_1+a_2+...+a_n$.
My attempt - $\frac{a_i}{s-a_i}>\frac{a_i}{s}$ for all $i$ from $1$ to $n$. Summing over all $i$, i got the lower bound as $1$ but the answer given is $\frac{n}{n-1}$

Comment: Search for Nesbitt's Inequality and generalize the proof for your case. Strangely enough, this inequality is not called *Generalized Nesbitt's Inequality*. Also search for *Rearrangement Inequality*.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  by the harmonic mean inequality:

$$
\frac{n}{\frac{1}{s-a_1}+\frac{1}{s-a_2}+...+\frac{1}{s-a_n}} \le \frac{(s-a_1)+(s-a_2)+\cdots+(s-a_n)}{n}=\frac{(n-1)s}{n} \\[5px]
 \iff\quad \frac{1}{s-a_1}+\frac{1}{s-a_2}+...+\frac{1}{s-a_n}\ge \frac{n^2}{(n-1)s}
$$

Then use the above in:

$$\frac{a_1\color{red}{-s+s}}{s-a_1}+\frac{a_2\color{red}{-s+s}}{s-a_2}+...+\frac{a_n\color{red}{-s+s}}{s-a_n}=s\left(\frac{1}{s-a_1}+\frac{1}{s-a_2}+...+\frac{1}{s-a_n}\right)-n$$

Equality is attained when all $a_k$ are equal.

Answer (score 1):

If $a_1=a_2=...=a_n=\frac{s}{n}$ we get a value $\frac{n}{n-1}$.

We'll prove that it's a minimal value.

Indeed, let $f(x)=\frac{x}{s-x}$.

Hence, $f''(x)=\frac{2s}{(s-x)^3}>0$ and our inequality follows from Jensen.

Indeed, $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_i}{s-a_i}\geq n\cdot\frac{\frac{s}{n}}{s-\frac{s}{n}}=\frac{n}{n-1}.$$
Done!

Another way.

Since our inequality is homogeneous, we can assume that $s=n$ and we need to prove that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_i}{n-a_i}\geq\frac{n}{n-1}$$ or
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{a_i}{n-a_i}-\frac{1}{n-1}\right)\geq0$$ or

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_i-1}{n-a_i}\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{a_i-1}{n-a_i}-\frac{a_i-1}{n-1}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(a_i-1)^2}{n-a_i}\geq0.$$
Done!

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality, assume that $a_1 \geq a_2 \geq \cdots \geq a_n$. Let $A = (a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)$ be the ordered n-tuple of given numbers and 
define $\sigma(A)$ to be the permutation of $A$ given by $\sigma(A) = (a_2, a_3, \dots, a_n, a_1)$. i.e. by shifting each number one index to the left and by sending the first number to the last place. We also define the *dot-product* of two ordered n-tuples $X = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ and $Y = (y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n)$ as follows: $X \cdot Y = x_1 y_1 + x_2 y_2 + \cdots + x_n y_n$.

By our assumption, it is easy to verify that $\frac{1}{s - a_1} \geq \frac{1}{s - a_2} \geq \cdots \geq \frac{1}{s - a_n}$. Now define the ordered n-tuple $B$ as follows: $B = (\frac{1}{s - a_1}, \frac{1}{s - a_2}, \dots, \frac{1}{s - a_n})$.

Then, by ***Rearrangement Inequality***, we have

$\begin{eqnarray*}
A \cdot B & \geq & \sigma(A) \cdot B \\
A \cdot B &\geq & \sigma^2(A) \cdot B \\
                & \vdots &                              \\
A \cdot B & \geq & \sigma^{n-1}(A) \cdot B
\end{eqnarray*}$

Adding these $n - 1$ inequalities, we get $(n - 1) A \cdot B \geq \sigma(A) \cdot B + \sigma^2(A) \cdot B + \cdots + \sigma^{n-1}(A) \cdot B$. It is easy to verify that $\sigma(A) \cdot B + \sigma^2(A) \cdot B + %
\cdots + \sigma^{n-1}(A) \cdot B = n$. Thus we get $A \cdot B \geq \frac{n}{n - 1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @dxiv's answer, but without harmonic:$$\frac{a_1\color{red}{-s+s}}{s-a_1}+\frac{a_2\color{red}{-s+s}}{s-a_2}+...+\frac{a_n\color{red}{-s+s}}{s-a_n}=s\left(\frac{1}{s-a_1}+\frac{1}{s-a_2}+...+\frac{1}{s-a_n}\right)-n$$
and apply Cauchy-Schwaz:
$$(s-a_1+s-a_2\cdots+s - a_n)\left(\frac{1}{s-a_1}+\frac{1}{s-a_2}+...+\frac{1}{s-a_n}\right)\ge n^2,$$
with note that
$$s-a_1+\cdots + s-a_n = (n-1)s.$$